# Stop hiding symbols on close, minimize and maximize window icons

Tags: macos, window-manager

On Mac, we have 3 circles:

- red : close
- yellow : minimize
- green: maximize

but the symbols on them are visible only on a mouse over event.

How could I make these symbols to be always visible?

Comment: You might wish to edit your question to include which version of macOS you're running.